# Django - limiting foreignkey queryset in single query

Tags: django, django-queryset

Let me first present model it will be easier to explain my question

```
Class A:
  points = Int

Class B:
  fk = ForignKey(A)
```

Let us assume that we have many A and B objects

```
top_a = A.objects.all().order_by("points")[:3]
result = B.objects.filter(fk__in=list(top_a))
```

Is there possibility of getting same results as above one but doing it in 1 single query? Result will be all of instances of B which have fk to one of A from top 3

Comment: I don't think it's possible to do it in one query, at least from sql query standpoint, because you always need a separate query to query on `A` for top 3 records anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do like:

```
result = B.objects.all().order_by('fk__points')[:3]
```

Comment: This result will give me 3 instances of B ;) Not all instances of B which have fk to one of top 3 of A